# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. plist

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I am trying to seed my app with data that is saved as an array of dictionarys `[[String:Any]]` in a plist file.

For the life of me, I cannot see what is wrong with this file though, it keeps giving me this error.

```
[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

What am I missing? Each dictionary is has uniform keys (12 of them). I have been trying to mess with this forever, and only weird thing I did was open up the Source Code to "Find and Replace" to change one of the keys.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Upper Dining Hall</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>3ebiuh8ph49j8dj55ni7nejb34@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string>https://amerifit.afvusa.com/MenuMain.aspx?a=NTgzMjEyMTU3</string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>U_food</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>West Dining Hall</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>j9miq3jg3hqp8trnc6suj0c498@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string>https://amerifit.afvusa.com/MenuMain.aspx?a=NTgzMjEyMTU3</string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>U_food</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Dutch Hollow</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>ajtrkgdb8ubklf4l1ppdt5jca8@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string>https://amerifit.afvusa.com/MenuMain.aspx?a=NTgzMjEyMTU3</string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>U_food</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>O3 Cafe</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>jntm4d5r86cpjts9tubd047bhs@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>U_food</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Ushi Bar</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>ke38tr4337ggbe53p7io37rbg8@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>U_food</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Rathskellar</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>r6gjugrdkdo4qfj01vm6dm5o10@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>campus-food</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Wold Starbucks</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>jpbte9scso7aj5ok06phdf283c@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>U_food</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>CPH Kiosk</string>
        <key>google_id</key>
        <string>k75eu5mebu858dormqtbj7rmbo@group.calendar.google.com</string>
        <key>google_calendar</key>
        <true/>
        <key>on_campus</key>
        <true/>
        <key>delivers</key>
        <false/>
        <key>delivery_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>reservation_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>menu_url</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>website</key>
        <string>http://uchospitality.com/</string>
        <key>phone</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>section</key>
        <string>U_food</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: which error have you get?

Comment: [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: If you got the Dev Tools from Apple installed, you can test for a correct plist format in your terminal with the plujtil command: example: "plutil test.plist" - see: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html

Comment: @Lepidopteron That's awesome, I just tried it. I got "test.plist: OK"

Comment: Do you really receive the error message when accessing the plist file or is there another process running in the background? Maybe there is a „hidden“ character in the plist, that you cannot see / is wrong? Have you tried to remove some parts of the plist and tried it once more?

Comment: The error comes specifically from trying to decode the data in the plist.